# how to clone python 2.7 installation + modules + packages in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, python-2.7

I have installed python in my mac osx 10.9 computer. I have also many packages and modules installed. I want to clone that installation into another computer. Which is the way to proceed? 
I do not want to re-install all of them from scratch, because I do not know exactly where/which/how those were. 
Any ideas?

Comment: *How* did you install the packages? If you've used `pip`, you can just `pip freeze > packages.txt` on machine A, copy that one file across then `pip install -r packages.txt` on machine B. Alternatively, if you managed your per-project dependencies better (e.g. with `virtualenv`s) you wouldn't have to do this at all.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. Some of them were installed via pip, so your suggestion should work for those. What do you mean by "you wouldn't have to do this at all?"

Comment: Ok, got the point about what you commented about virtualenv. Thanks.